# Xephyr восстановить

Tags: linux

Подключаюсь к удаленному компьютеру через Xephyr, запускаю несколько оконных программ.

Если по ошибке закрыть окно Xephyr, программы остаются работать. Если позже запустить Xephyr снова с этими же параметрами, то открытых окон не видно (хотя они продолжают работать, это видно в списке процессов). Как увидеть открытые приложения снова?

Comment: попробуй xspice или xvnc. они удобнее